# PdfWriter Python how to update field with multiline text

Tags: python, newline, pdf-writer

I've been trying for hours to insert a multiline text into a PDF with Python but none of the potential solutions worked. I've looked at multiple libraries and other solutions but none of them were using PdfWriter or helped solve my problem
Here are a few of my tries:

- \n
- \r
- \t
- unicode characters for tabs and returns
- textwrap
- \u0009
  But none of them work. It produces the pdf with the correct text but it doesn't go to the new line.

The pdf can be found [here](https://5.imimg.com/data5/SELLER/Doc/2021/4/QI/LK/YD/7115850/pdf-conversion-services.pdf)

Here is my code:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter


file_path = os.path.join(script_directory, 'folder/', 'sample.pdf')
reader = PdfReader(file_path)
page_0 = reader.pages[0]
writer = PdfWriter()
writer.add_page(page_0)
name = current_user.name
address = session['address']

writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[0], {"1": f'{name}\r\n{address}'})
with open(os.path.join(script_directory, 'folder/', 'sample_filled_out.pdf'), "wb") as output_stream:
   writer.write(output_stream)
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is the pdf already exist ? or you create new one ? provide the code you use to do that if you can

Comment: The pdf already exists yes. It's creating a filled out pdf, I've edited the question with more information sorry about that, hopefully all is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to have the library write multiline variables, so the better solution was to separate the two fields into unique fields with different id's and then individually access each like so:

```
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[0], {"1": name})
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[0], {"2": address})
```

Thanks for everyone who commented on the post trying to help.